# Usefulness of debugging symbols together with optimizations

Tags: c++, c, debugging, compiler-optimization

I would like to understand how debugging symbols can still be useful when compiling with `-g -O2` in `gcc` or `clang`.

Because I understand, the compiler first adds the debugging symbols, and then apply all the optimizations, while not modifying or updating the debugging symbols in agreement with the modifications being performed over the code, so that any of the following situations could happen while debugging if optimizations are in place:

- Breakpoints could mess up, in the sense that I could potentially no longer be able to pause in meaninful places: if I say, pause "here", such "here" could no longer exists anymore or refer to some other random place, and so I'm no longer able to pause where I intended.
- Trying to read the value of certain variable that no longer exists could cause a crash, because according to the symbol the variable is still at some memory address, but since the variable doesn't exist anymore, reading that memory address could cause a segfault.
- In case of an exception or a signal like segfault, the debugger could point me out to a line of code that has nothing to do with the actual point of failure.

Even if I could study/understand the generated assembly output, the debugging symbols are still useless because they have been "frozen" respect to the original code (in my understanding), so the debugging symbols are no longer coherent with the current shape of the code. So even if I could understand the current optimized code, the debugging symbols can't help me debug the code nor respect to the original code, neither respect to the final code.

Are my line of thoughts correct? How are debugging symbols that have been activated with `-g` still useful together with `-O2`?

I'm asking this question because I'm reading that using the combo `-g -O2` is relatively common, which means that it must be still useful somehow, but I can't figure it out how, taking into account that you can trust debugging symbols anymore.

Comment: Using `-g -O2` can be useful for debugging problems involving undefined behavior where the optimization exposes problems.  It can also be useful in production for symbolicating core dumps.  One alternative to the debugging UB approach is using sanitizers like `-fsanitize=undefined,null,address,bounds,float-divide-by-zero` to help root out those kinds of problems.

Comment: Yep, debugging optimised code with symbols is tricky and unreliable but debugging it without symbols is worse. If you can reproduce a problem in debug mode then that's always the better option but it's not unusual to run into bugs that don't happen in debug

Comment: @Eljay but how is still useful if you are blind respect to where the undefined behaviour happens? The most useful thing you can do I guess is asking for the stack trace, and that's mostly all, but for that I guess you don't need the general `-g` option, but you can choose some specific, less expensive, debugging option.

Comment: It is still useful because you get symbolicated information, and you **can** still debug the program — even though optimizations making it a bit more difficult.

Comment: Try actually debugging some code - you'll soon see it has value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding of *why* debug symbols in optimized code don't work as you'd expect isn't quite right.

The debugging symbols are produced to match the final object code, which is to say the optimized code. There's no "updating" needed during optimization because the debugging information hasn't yet been saved out. (Of course, it's *there* already, in the form of the compiler's internal data structures, but it doesn't need to be updated separately from those structures.)

Rather, the reason that debugging optimized code is weird is because (a) there's no longer a simple and monotonic mapping between lines of code and CPU instructions, and (b) there's no longer a simple mapping between variables and registers/memory locations.

In particular:

> Breakpoints could mess up, in the sense that I could potentially no longer be able to pause in meaninful places: if I say, pause "here", such "here" could no longer exists anymore or refer to some other random place, and so I'm no longer able to pause where I intended.

The compiler isn't required to output a program that does things in the order you specified. Suppose your program has the snippet `a = b*c + d; f = g - h;`, and suppose the compiler decides that the final program should multiply `b` and `c` before it subtracts `h` from `g`, but add `d` *after* that subtraction. So does the first line of code come before or after the second one? well, both! The compiler does the best it can to preserve a halfway reasonable mapping, though. You'll end up in *a reasonably related place*.

> Trying to read the value of certain variable that no longer exists could cause a crash, because according to the symbol the variable is still at some memory address, but since the variable doesn't exist anymore, reading that memory address could cause a segfault.

Well, no, it won't. The debugger isn't going to crash, even if it does try to read an invalid location, which it likely wouldn't anyway because the page would probably still be mapped to the executable. But there's no requirement that a variable be in the same "place" (memory location or register) all the time. Different compilers, and different compiler versions, do a better or worse job of tracking where the variable is right now. But as you said, it may not exist at a given moment.

> In case of an exception or a signal like segfault, the debugger could point me out to a line of code that has nothing to do with the actual point of failure.

This is potentially true even with unoptimized code, if stack smashing occurs (which it often does just before a segfault). Otherwise this is really just a variant of the first issue: "the actual point of failure" is not a line of code, it's an instruction. So the compiler has to decide what line of code (if any) the instruction most closely relates to.

Compilers vary in their ability to output reasonable and helpful debugging information for optimized code. IMO Visual C++ is by far the best, and Clang is better than GCC, but it really depends on the type of optimization and the version of the compiler.

Bottom line: there are obvious deficiencies in the information you get from debugging information for optimized code. But as someone once said "I know it's crooked, but it's the only game in town". Seeing a segfault in `StringMuncher::chew()` may or may not indicate that the `chew()` function is *actually* to blame, but it *probably* is, and is that better or worse than only seeing that the segfault is at address 0x6AE002E0?

There are various techniques one can use to help debugging optimized code, but those are out of scope for this question, and have probably already been described in a different question.

Answer (score 3):

> Are my line of thoughts correct? How are debugging symbols that have
> been activated with -g still useful together with -O2?

Lets go through them one by one:

---

> `Breakpoints could mess up`

**Yes**. *Some* (not all) positions in your code **might** not be reached *at all* (dead code elimination), *multiple times* (inlining, unrolling, ...), *out of order*, etc. Notice the qualification though. While this makes debugging a lot less pleasant, the source location annotations remaining in the binary can still help you a lot in figuring out what is going on e.g. right before a crash.

---

> Trying to read the value of certain variable that no longer exists could cause a crash

**Mostly no.** If your debugger is worth it's salt, it will not crash if you attempt to print out a symbol that is not present in the debug symbols. It might sometimes claim that the location is unreadable, or (rarely) report incorrect data. Again, the compiler will attempt to  keep as much of this information useful and updated as possible while running it's optimization passes. So many variables **will** still be readable, and can be very helpful for crash debugging. Especially heap memory will (mostly) stay intact.

---

> In case of an exception or a signal like segfault, the debugger could point me out to a line of code that has nothing to do with the actual point of failure.

**Partially.** The **assembly instruction** that the debugger will report to have caused the crash will definitely be correct. The *corresponding source location annotation* will be the *best effort* attempt by the compiler, which may not be perfect. It will most likely be very close though, and can still be **very** helpful. Especially useful in cases where the  crash **only** happens in release mode, e.g. due to race conditions or the compiler's interpretation of undefined behavior in your code.

---

> Even if I could study/understand the generated assembly output, the debugging symbols are still useless because they have been "frozen" respect to the original code (in my understanding)

**Partially.** As stated before, The *source locations* are a *best effort" attempt by the compiler. This can be a bit jumbled up in release mode, but it is not at all **useless**.
See this example: https://godbolt.org/z/xKsEE98rs . Godbolt colors in the assembly lines according to their source location information. In release mode (O3 here), these correspond much less directly to the source, but some structure is still noticable. In fact, you could claim that the source locations are *more* important in release mode here, because otherwise you would have no idea at all what is going on.

Comment: Formatting note: don't use `code formatting` for highlighting or quoting.  That makes it very bad for some screen readers, apparently, among other reasons.  I'd recommend using `> text` quote blocks to quote the OP's statements before a paragraph that addresses them.  Sometimes I also `---` hrule to separate sections,   (Nice answer, though.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: changed accordingly, wasn't aware of the accessability issues. Thanks for the `---` tip, the missing separation was what kept me away from block quotes.